# Angular-cli: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'PouchDB'

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, pouchdb

#### OS?

> Linux (Amazon Linux AMI)

#### Versions.

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.22-1
node: 6.6.0
os: linux x64
```

#### Repro steps.

I installed recently PouchDB:

```
npm i pouchdb --save
npm i @types/pouchdb --save-dev
```

I added this in **typings.d.ts**:

```
declare module 'PouchDB';
```

And now I import PouchDB in my service:

```
import * as PouchDB from 'PouchDB';
```

Well, all is okey in my laptop (MacOS Sierra); `ng serve`, `ng build` without problems and PouchDB is working well.

But... Not the same thing in my server (Amazon Linux AMI)...

I'm getting the next error trying to execute `ng build`:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/pictures.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'PouchDB' in '/home/aral/project/src/app'
 @ ./src/app/pictures.service.ts 11:0-35
 @ ./src/app/app.module.ts
 @ ./src/app/index.ts
 @ ./src/main.ts
 @ multi main
```

I have the same angular-cli version and node version that in my laptop...

And I compared doing `tree` command in my laptop and my server and both have the same files. (Except some sub-dependency in `node_modules`).

*Thank you!*

---

*Issue reported in GitHub: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3698*

Comment: is typings required with npm @types ?

Comment: yes. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Mac in my laptop and this is the reason why in my laptop don't have this issue: Because the Mac main filesystem is case **insensitive**. Linux is not so forgiving. So importing from PouchDB the system is looking for a node_modules names PouchDB, but it's really named pouchdb (**lowercase**).

Answer (score 0):

Checking in package.json file whether the pounchbd dependency is included or not,
if it is not included, then add this dependency  "pouchdb": "^7.2.2" and run npm install